# How to complete file pathname using javascript

Tags: javascript, path

Is it possible (and how) to create a file path if I know part of file pathname?
For example I have file pathname /User/Documents/Italy/Report_123.pdf
How to complete pathname if I know there is pdf in folder Italy which contain word Report_ those numbers at the end are dynamic?

I need to complete this task in javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the context of this? Please may you add a [mcve] of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I am assuming you are using node? Please add tags appropriately.

Comment: xSorry for misunderstanding , I'm pretty new to this, I'll try to be more precise. I want to read some information from pdf. I know that there is some pdf called Report_ but I don't know which combination of numbers will be at the end. Can I somehow create pathname even I don't now full file name?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using node.js, you can get all the files from that folder, then you iterate that result array to get the one you want.

```js
import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';


const result = await readdir('C:/User/Documents/Italy');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this it may be helps you

```
var documentName = "Report_123.pdf";    // Use documentName Variable to use other js functions for example - documentName.split("_").
var path = "../User/Documents/Italy/"+documentName;
```

Comment: Thank you, We are getting closer to a solution
Another important feature is that each file has a 3-digits  at the end of name Report_XXX 
I heard somewhere, but I'm not sure, that there is a sign(special character) that changes any character in the string? maybe this is important hint for you